# How to try clicking on elements in Playwright without try except block?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have this code:

```
def try_close_error_popup(self):
        try:
            self.page.locator(
                self.CLOSE, has_text='Close').click(timeout=1200)
        except TimeoutError:
            LOGGER.info('Failed to click close popup button')
```

I noticed that the try/except blocks make my code to run much slower. Is there a way I can just try finding and element and clicking on it without getting an error?

Comment: What if you directly use the click statement without try-except statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (page.is_visible(XPATH)):
    page.click(XPATH)
```

Or you can make the code cleaner like this:

```
try:
    page.click(XPATH)
except:
    pass
```